# Docker compose and Service communication

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose with 5 services that have to communicate.
I checked whether they would be in the same network using `docker network inspect networkname_dafult`
and I could find all the apps there in the same network.
The result of inspect returned a json with a name property.

````
            ```"Name": "app_1",```
````

In each service I am using that name to make http requests but they return
`"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5003"` for example.

If I access localhost:5003 it works, and it will work for each service.

If i try to make the http requests from my apps using localhost:port it wont work either.

My dockercompose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    App1:
        image: user/app1
        ports:
           - 5001:5001
        links:
            - App2
            - App3
            - App4
            - App5
        hostname: app1
    App2:
        image: user/app2
        ports:
           - 5002:5002
        hostname: app2
    App3:
        image: user/app3
        ports:
           - 5003:5003
        hostname: app3
    App4:
        image: user/app4
        ports:
           - 5004:5004
        hostname: app4
    App5:
        image: user/app5
        ports:
           - 5005:5005
        hostname: app5
```

I tried to make the http requests using the hostname, Appx and etc... I cant make them communicate with each other.

What might I be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker-compose already creates a default network.
I ran `docker network ls` to see which networks were available
and used `docker network inspect mynetwork` to see if the apps on my docker-compose were running on the same network (They will be).

The result of docker network inspect is an array of containers objects.
Each container object has a name property (That was the information I nedded to make http connections between services)

```
 "Containers": {
            "01fcacc2b2dc8450c5c75e": {
                "Name": "myapp_1",
                "EndpointID": "9e3fa9633d9d1692d4f7120c",
                "MacAddress": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
                "IPv4Address": "172.33.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
```

On each service I was performing http requests I used that property name to make the requests.

```
axios.get(http://myapp_1)
```

An important detail was to rebuild my container after changing it!

`docker build -t myapp .`

When I ran docker-compose again everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a network and assign all the parts of the service to that network. One example:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  App1:
    image: user/app1
    ports:
       - 5001:5001
    networks:
       - app_net
    hostname: app1
  App2:
    image: user/app2
    ports:
       - 5002:5002
    networks:
       - app_net
    hostname: app2
  App3:
    image: user/app3
    ports:
       - 5003:5003
    networks:
       - app_net
    hostname: app3
  App4:
    image: user/app4
    ports:
      - 5004:5004
    networks:
      - app_net
    hostname: app4
  App5:
    image: user/app5
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    networks:
      - app_net
    hostname: app5
```

But it might be that I'm missing something. Another thing to consider is using `links` - more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links). Also, if you are going to copy+paste this code, take care about indentation.

Comment: Docker already created a network when I ran docker-compose and all the services are being listed on that network.
I will still try your suggestion because I am curious. But Thanks!

Comment: The problem was that I actually forgot to rebuild my image with the updated code and the request has to be called with the container name that I found using docker network inspect mynetwork

Comment: Compose creates a `default` network for you; you don't have to manually configure it like this.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has additional details.